# What is the best practice to add more policy after limit is reached in a AWS IAM group?

Tags: amazon-iam

I would like to know what is the best way to handle policy in a group.

As you can see in the screenshot, I have already attached 10 policy to the group

[image]

I would like to give the group members the permission query IAM.

I reckon I can create one more group to contain this permission and put my IAM users in the new group. However I would like to know if there is any better solution.